# convert sparse format to array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose you have a generator that returns the rows of a table. Something you could use like this:

```
for (labels, value) in rows:
    pass
```

"labels" is length n and say it's all strings for simplicity. "value" is something numeric like a float.

Is there a fast, best or built-in way to hash the labels and end up with an n-dimensional array of values and n lists telling you how to map the labels values to indices? I think you could maybe store this in a recarray? I do this all the time but it always ends up being a bit of throw away code. I'd like to find or create something more reusable.

I would be very happy with 
`(('here', 'there', 'nowhere'), 1.234)` being mapped to either `results['here']['there']['nowhere'] = 1.234` or `results[12,3,45] = 1.234` (and having the corresponding lists given the labels down the axes in each dimension.)

I could probably write generator conversion to sparse format and use scipy, but this seems like a nasty way to do something relatively simple.

I see a lot of similar sounding questions but none which exactly answer this question. Maybe  I'm missing a search phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a structured array:

```
result = np.fromiter(your_generator, dtype=[('labels', '|S10'), ('value', float)])
```

You'll be able to retrieve a `ndarray` of labels as `result['labels']` (and the values as `result['value']`, of course).

Note that you could store several entries in the same label (provided you always have the same number), like in

```
result = np.array([(('a','b','c'), 1.23),(('a','c','d'), 2.34)],
                  dtype=[('label', ("|S10", 3)), ('value', float)])
```

where each individual record is given as a tuple, and the three 'labels' of a record as a tuple themselves. You can also name each 'label' individually using a tailored dtype, for example:

```
 dtype=[('label',[('A','|S10'),('B','|S10'),('C','|S10')]),('value',float)]
```

This way, you could access all the `A` through `result['label']['A']`...

Comment: This is just returning what I already have ... I don't want to hash the columns, I want to hash the rows. I'll update the question. I don't think I was being very clear.